# query like shell_exec("echo %username%") doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I simply have a query :

```
$username=shell_exec("echo %username%" ); //Give Qsr042
$Name=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM user WHERE Login like "'.$username.'"'))['Name']; //Doesn't work
```

But when i do a `echo gettype($Name);`, it says it's NULL.

In mysql I have 'Qsr042' as Login because if my query is :

```
$Name=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM user WHERE Login like "Qsr042"'))['Name']; //Works
```

Now it simply works. Everything is a string so it should work... 
What have i missed ?

Comment: For escaping strings in mysql you should use single quotes.

Comment: Doesn't work... but thanks for answering

Comment: Are you aware of the mysqli error (http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php) methods?

Comment: Can you check for errors while querying?

Comment: Return nothing. I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why it didn't work. I used `$username=trim(shell_exec('echo %username%'))` and it worked. I'm not sure why but i won't complain. Thank you for trying helping me

Answer (score 0):

shell_exec will execute the shell commands not PHP functions 
e.g.

$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "

```
$output
```

";

Comment: `$output = shell_exec('ls -lart'); echo "$output";` doesn't return anything.
`echo gettype ($output)` is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Because you've got a return at the end.

Do a `rtrim()` :

```
$username=shell_exec("echo %username%" ); //Give Qsr042 (with \r\n)
$username=rtrim($username); //Give Qsr042
$Name=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM user WHERE Login like "'.$username.'"'))['Name'];
```